# Redirect /web url to / Symfony

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, redirect

My website is build with Symfony3.
I'm in front on a problem .

> mywebsite.com/contact

is also accessible as

> mywebsite.com/web/contact

I want to redirect all urls like mywebsite.com/web/something to mywebsite.com/something

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong configruation of your RootFolder, you need to setup your virtual hosts correctly

Comment: I'm am not on a dedical server, so i use htaccess

Comment: Even if not the routing of symfony relies on the document root.... as well as the assetic management does